# What to import for -?> in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to use [`-?>`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_contrib/1.2.0/clojure.contrib.core/-_q%3E) in Clojure but get the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: -?> in this context
```

What do I need to import in order to use it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you need to add a dependency on `core.incubator` to your project.clj (if you aren't using [leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen), that should be your first step):

```
:dependencies [...
               [org.clojure/core.incubator "0.1.1"]]
```

Next, you can use it in your code like this:

```
(ns myapp.core
  (:use [clojure.core.incubator :only [-?>]]))
```

If you're using Clojure 1.4, this will also work:

```
(ns myapp.core
  (:require [clojure.core.incubator :refer [-?>]]))
```

And is preferable if you don't plan to support Clojure pre-1.4 versions of Clojure.

Comment: It would appear that `-?>` is not available in 1.3.

Comment: Yes, it is. Why would you think otherwise?

Comment: The clojuredocs.org link only indicates 1.2 http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_contrib/1.2.0/clojure.contrib.core/-_q%3E